# JQGrid Count rows in a group

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid that displays some data grouped by a certain column. i wish to show the count of rows next to the group name. anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GroupText](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3agrouping&s%5B%5D=grouptext) field for indicating the count:

> An array that defines the grouping header text for the group level that will be
>   displayed in the grid. By default if defined the value if {0} which
>   means that the group value name will be displayed. It is possible to
>   specify another value {1} which meant the the total count of this group
>   will be displayed too. It is possible to set here any valid html
>   content.

Example:

```
groupingView: {
     groupField:['GroupField'],
     groupText: ['<b>{0} - {1} Item(s)</b>']
}
```